# Weird pinched shading from bevel and subdivision

Tags: modifiers

I have this peculiar shading issue on this pipe that I'm making, only apears after I add a bevel and a subdiv modifier, also after shading smooth. In the center of the pipe, I have this ridge extruded out:
[image: Pipe]

on the corners of the ridge where it bevels into the pipe, I'm getting this weird pinched shading

[image: shading issue]

I've got the edges marked with bevel weight

[image: bevel]

I've tried adding loop cuts to constrain the issue but I'm still being left with odd shading artifacts

[image]

These are the settings I have for the modifiers. I've tried playing around with them, but I just can't seem to iron it out. I'm on vanilla blender, so no hardops quick fixes.

[image]

Comment: Hello :). Combining Bevel and Subsurf on corners [can cause problems](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/123617/78972). You can mitigate them (with loops, creases, clever geometry) but they'll always be there. I'd either use only Bevel, or only Subsurf.