# Problem using Bevel and Subdivision Workflow

Tags: modeling, edges, subdivision-surface, topology, bevel

I am trying to model a simple piece of a sniper scope. For that I am using a Bevel and Subdivision modifier to get clean and crisp edges when raising the model's resolution.

this is what the topology looks like without any modifier active:

[image]

As you can see it is based on a simple cylinder, nothing fancy. Next you can see the beveled topology. I want each beveled edge to stay sharp when subdividing.

[image]

However when I add the subdivision modifier on top I get a weird pinching effect in the areas I marked red. see the image:

[image]

I have to admit this is a problem that comes around pretty often but I never figured out how to fix it yet. I already tried adding some support loops, but it is important to me to keep the perfect circular shape of the scope part.

If you are reading this and know what to do in this case I would be more than happy if you could give some advice. Please find the blend file attached.

[blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1v0IOsu2vTS1NPZudKTx16uGaiPlRkcBV/view?usp=sharing)
[blend file from pasteall.org](https://pasteall.org/blend/797579bd898d47dab823ea1e790595ba)

Comment: Hello :). I believe RobinBetts and Leander adressed this in some older thread...

Comment: Here it is: [How to avoid pinching on concave shapes with the bevel modifier and subsurf?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/123617/78972)

Comment: @jachymMichal thanks for your reply! I already came across his answer, but his solution relies on additional edge loops. As soon as I add additional edge loops to my model I break the circular edge flow of the scope and the silhouette is no more perfectly circular from the front view

Comment: Try setting the Miter outer to 'Arc' under Geometry in the Bevel modifier.

Comment: @ Jachym Michal  it doesn't matter, I NEED to ask!!!!

Comment: @JohnEason nice tip, starts to look way better. The Downside of it is that it creates Ngons that are also still noticeable when having a closer look after subdividing.

Comment: @moonboots I updated the post with a pasteall.org link

Comment: Try to add bevel weights. I found answer in this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R73wtu1Ixnw
minute 1:20 Or change bevel settings from angle to vertex

Answer (score 3):

You probably need more topology, like this (use a *Shrinkwrap* to make it stick to a cylinder shape):

[image]

The pinching is almost not noticeable:

[image]

If you want a better result I guess you need to add more topology:

[image]

[image]