# Measuring edge angle relative to faces normals (negative angles allowed), and automatically select similar

Tags: edges, selection-tools

Ive got a mesh, and Im wanting to select all acute edges with angles relative to their adjacent faces to a certain degree.  But it seems that even if a connection between two faces is flexing inward, or outward, the sign of the angle stays the same.  Is there any way to allow signed angles for use in the "Select similar" tool?  Im using blender 2.92.0

Or if not, how do I select edges that bend inward to a certain degree?

Here is a screenshot showing what happens, and in red of what behavior Im looking for.  If I were to select edge C, and select similar with a tolerance of 50 degrees, It would only select C and A, not B (as this is the default behavior)
[image]

Comment: Hello :). This script by Leander could help: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/124206/78972